# On n'arrêtera pas les antibiotiques jusqu'à ce que l'on (ne) fasse (pas) un deuxième scan

Tags: négation, conjonctions, double-négation

> On n'arrêtera pas les antibiotiques jusqu'à ce que l'on **ne** fasse **pas**
> un deuxième scan.
>
> On arrêtera les antibiotiques seulement après les résultats du
> deuxième scan, au cas où ce serait possible.

Les deux phrases ont le même sens. La deuxième phrase est correcte. Est-ce que la première est correcte, elle aussi ? J'hésite quant à la négation dans la deuxième partie *ne fasse pas un deuxième scan*.

Answer (score 2):

> … jusqu'à ce que l'on ne fasse pas un deuxième scan.

Cette phrase est grammaticalement correcte, mais est un non-sens. Elle ne peut pas avoir le même sens que la deuxième phrase. « A jusqu'à ce que B » signifie que A est vrai sur une période de temps qui se termine quand l'évènement ponctuel B arrive, ou éventuellement que A est vrai sur une période de temps qui dure au moins jusqu'à l'évènement ponctuel B et peut se prolonger après.

```
                 B
                 ↓
──────────────────────────→ temps
   └─────────────┘
            A
```

ou

```
                 B
                 ↓
──────────────────────────→ temps
   └──────────────────┘
            A
```

La proposition « … jusqu'à ce que l'on ne fasse pas un deuxième scan » ne peut avoir de sens que s'il y a un moment identifiable où l'on ne fait pas un deuxième scan. Ce ne peut arriver que dans des circonstances inhabituelles qui devraient être expliquées par le contexte. Par exemple : « nous garderons le patient en observation jusqu'à ce qu'il refuse le deuxième scan que nous lui proposerons mardi » (étant sous-entendu que le patient peut en principe accepter ou refuser le deuxième scan, mais la personne qui parle est convaincue qu'il va le refuser).

---

Tu penses peut-être au *« ne » explétif*, mais il est impossible ici. Le « ne » explétif n'est utilisé que dans des clauses hypothétiques, par exemple « on n'arrêtera pas les antibiotiques à moins qu'un deuxième scan *ne* montre que la tumeur a complètement disparu ». De plus, le « ne » explétif n'est pas une négation : ajouter *pas* rendrait la proposition négative et inverserait donc son sens (« on arrêtera les antibiotiques à moins qu'un deuxième scan *ne* montre *pas* que la tumeur a complètement disparu » ­— mais plus vraisemblablement « on arrêtera les antibiotiques à moins qu'un deuxième scan ne montre que la tumeur n'a pas complètement disparu », la différence entre ces deux phrases étant le cas où le scan serait non conclusif et ne permettrait pas de voir si la tumeur a disparu).

Comment: *On n'arrêtera pas les antibiotiques tant qu'on n'aura pas un deuxième scan positif/sain.*

Comment: @jlliagre Oui, merci ! C'est ce que je voulais dire.

Comment: Merci. J'ai traduit mot à mot du russe. Cette phrase est possible en russe, et elle signifie ce que jlliagre a écrit dans le premier commentaire. :)

Comment: Ou plutôt : _On n'arrêtera pas les antibiotiques à moins que le deuxième scan ne détecte aucune anomalie._ Ou : _On n'arrêtera pas les antibiotiques tant qu'on n'aura pas le deuxième scan ne présentant aucune anomalie._

Comment: *On n'arrêtera pas les antibiotiques tant qu'on n'aura pas de scan ne présentant aucune anomalie.* Un "scan sain", c'est bien un scan ne présentant aucune anomalie. Scan positif est ambigu.

Comment: @jlliagre Oui, c'est la meilleure. Mais si la situation est la suivante : on fera le 2ème scan dans qq semaines / mois. S'il n'y a aucune anomalie, on arrêtera les médicaments. S'il y a toujours des abcès, on envisagera une chirurgie plus complexe. Donc, la phrase _On n'arrêtera pas les antibiotiques à moins que le deuxième scan ne détecte aucune anomalie_ serait la plus exacte ?  // D'accord, j'avais l'impression que  _un scan sain_ sonne bizarrement.

Comment: _On va continuer la prise d'antibiotiques jusqu'à un examen ultérieur démontrant..._, ou _tant et aussi longtemps qu'on..._ Parfois un autre choix de verbe facilite la tâche. @Oreste